# Java Input Stream buffer destiny after read

Tags: java, android, inputstream, tcpclient, inputstreamreader

I'm working with TCPClient socket on Android platform and need to keep connection open and send/recieve data from server while application running...
As I noticed we have to call getInputStream method of socket class in order to read data. A question comes to mind after reading some data from InputStream/InputStreamReader/BufferedReader what will happen to the memory used for data. does java free the memory block after read? do we need to call reset method after reading whole single data packet?

Comment: Refer to this blog to understand the significance of InputStream - https://pwdd.github.io/post/improving-memory-usage-of-a-java-server. Memory used for data in InputStream is not for storage, it is meant for streaming the data. Actual storage is implementation-dependent.

Comment: Interesting resource related to its topic. but i still couldn't got the answer. what will happen to the data memory after read. If java not free the memory after read, the memory for incoming data will get bigger and bigger and finally app will face memory related error.

Comment: That's what it says, memory won't get bigger in InputStream. That's the reason why InputStream is used.